# 'error: BrokenCount>0'

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

it says this on the bottom right of my computer, 
its says ''this usually means that you installed packages that have unmet dependecies.''

I did Run `df -i` in terminal and it gave me this :

```
udev            214773    487  214286    1% /dev
tmpfs           219974    657  219317    1% /run
/dev/sda1      9740288 443560 9296728    5% /
tmpfs           219974      1  219973    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           219974      5  219969    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           219974     15  219959    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           219974     21  219953    1% /run/user/1000
```

If I try  apt-get update I get this :

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Last thing I tried was : `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core`

It said :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: libdpkg-perl but it is not installed
```

Comment: try  `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: try   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: post the output of those commands in your post. report back if they work.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy dh-python libdpkg-perl; sudo apt-get install -y libdpkg-perl`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, and this is **really rare**, the package system blocks itself. In this case, it is worthwhile to install that problematic package (`libdpkg-perl`) by hand himself. So in your case, as confirmed your comment.

```
sudo apt-get install libdpkg-perl
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: thanks the error message is no longer here, therefore I cannot access the internet...